# Use value in another method

Tags: c#

I am trying to use value in another method, for example in the code below I have this value userPostedFile.FileName:

```
public partial class _WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload");
    HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
    Span1.Text = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

        if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));

            Span1.Text += "Location where saved: " + filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";

        }}}
```

and I want to use it in the code below, but I am getting an error which is:
the name doesn't exist in the current context:

```
     private int get_pageCcount(string file)
     {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(userPostedFile.FileName)))
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());

        return matches.Count;

         }}}
```

Comment: Please do not take this the wrong way, but you might want to read up on some programming basics first. Specifically the concept of "Scope" of variables. In this case you declare the variable inside the for-loop, which makes it available __only__ inside the braces of the loop itself. If you want to use it in a different scope (the get_pageCount function) you will have to declare the variable in a scope that is common to both the loop and the function (e.g. "outside" both of their scopes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the name doesn't exist in the current context:

A context or scope is defined within the curly brackets: `{` and `}`. This is where the variable "lives" and can be found.
`userPostedFile` is declared as a local variable in the scope of the for-loop. It will neither be accessible outside of the loop, nor outside of the method!
For more information please read [Scopes C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)

Inside the loop the assignment of this variable changes in each iteration:

```
HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
```

So even if you would declare the variable `userPostedFile` on class level, which would make it accessible in the `get_pageCcount` method, it would be unclear which instance you would use in the line:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(userPostedFile.FileName)))
```

Lets say you would declare the variable in the scope of the class like you have done with `filepath` and `uploadedFiles`

```
public partial class _WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    HttpPostedFile userPostedFile;

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload");
    HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
    Span1.Text = string.Empty;

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
```

The variable `userPostedFile` will now be accessible in the `get_pageCcount` method. But it depends now strongly on **when** you call the method. If you call it before the button click. You will get a `NullReferenceException` because `userPostedFile` has not been given any value yet. If you call it after the button click you will get the last value of `uploadedFiles` because it will have the value that was assigned at the end of the loop.

Comment: @azza I am glad to hear, but do you really want to use only the last value of `uploadedFiles` in the `get_pageCcount` method? Or do you want to use exactly the last value of `uploadedFiles` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `userPostedFile.FileName` outside your `Button1_Click` method. Your variable is declared inside your `Button1_Click`, so it can only be called inside it. That's why **the name doesn't exist in the current context** is showing.

You should atleast assign the `userPostedFile` to a variable outside your `Button1_Click` or just declare the `userPostedFile` outside of your `Button1_Click` method. You can do it like this:

Example:

```
public partial class _WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

HttpPostedFile userPostedFile;

public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload");
    HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
    Span1.Text = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

        if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));

            Span1.Text += "Location where saved: " + filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";

        }}}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public partial class _WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 HttpPostedFile userPostedFile;// İf declare userPostedFile in this scope
                                // u can use another scopes but  last value
                                // in for loop                             
  public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload");
  HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
  Span1.Text = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
{
    userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

    if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));

        Span1.Text += "Location where saved: " + filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";

    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use global vars if the methods are in the same class

```
public partial class _WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = null;
     public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload");
          HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
          Span1.Text = string.Empty;

          for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
          {
               userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
```

and now you can use this in your method.

But if your method is in another class you must define this global var like this:

```
 public static HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = null;
```

and use this

```
 _WebForm1.userPostedFile.FileName
```